# How to Stage Files for Compression

Tags: java, image-compression, compression

I am extremely interested in writing a data compression library of my own.  All my Google searches turn up results where people are saying "Just use the included Java libraries."  That is not what I am looking for.

For instance, I have written a Java application that takes in an image file, conducts mathematical compression on it, and writes it to a file.  Once I attempt to uncompress the file, I am not able to view the image.  In fact, the uncompressed file is slightly smaller in size than the original image.

So, my question is, what is the proper way to maintain data integrity throughout the compression process?  Let's say, for example, I simply sum the natural logarithms of each byte value.  When I take that final value, how can I ensure that I do not lose any data during the reversal process?

Comment: You may want to do some research on Lossy vs Lossless compression algorithms. A lossless algorithm would always restore the exact same file. Lossy compression (JPEG format uses this) gives a result that is "good enough".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I get the differences between the two.  I know lossy will make the file inherently smaller because they either quantize datasets or remove unnecessary data.  However, I just performed a reversible mathematical function on each byte and then reversed it, but the file is still corrupted.  So, somewhere in the compression/decompression process, I am losing data and I cannot figure out how it is happening.

Comment: I'd suggest making some unit tests and trying on very small data sizes. Compression is usually an all-or-nothing kind of thing with lossless, so you don't care about integrity as it is running because you already know it works correctly. Checksums for integrity could be useful if the data is being passed in an unreliable way (ie. network), but otherwise the integrity of an algorithm can be proven with unit tests.

Comment: Mathematical functions that use finite-precision data types are not generally "reversible." Write a unit test that validates the reversibility, and I expect you may find your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I'll go ahead and build a unit test for a small dataset.  I'll get back to you with results.